# How to use get changing y variables each graph using facet in ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

So I'm working with a dataframe pictured below - I want to use facet in a way so that each graph produced by the facet will compare the variable "Status" with the rest of the variables.

Status is a character variable, and this will be my x-axis for all of the graph:

[image]

I don't want to use ggplot for this as I'm specifically trying to get it to work in ggpubr.

```
gg <- ggviolin(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg, x = "Status", y = 
colnames(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg)[2:19],
     fill = "Status",
     palette = "hsv",
     title = "xCell Score Comparisons between HNSC+, HNSC-, and CESC+",
     ylab = colnames(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg)[2:19],
     na.rm = TRUE,
     facet.by = colnames(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg)[2:19],
     add = "boxplot")+
stat_compare_means(comparison = comp1)+
geom_jitter(alpha = 0.125, size = .75)+
theme_classic()`
```

I also tried this:

```
gg <- ggviolin(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg, x = "Status", y = colnames(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg)[2:19],
     fill = "Status",
     palette = "hsv",
     title = "xCell Score Comparisons between HNSC+, HNSC-, and CESC+",
     ylab = colnames(cesc_vs_hnsc_pos_vs_hnsc_neg)[2:19],
     na.rm = TRUE,
     add = "boxplot")+
stat_compare_means(comparison = comp1)+
geom_jitter(alpha = 0.125, size = .75)+
theme_classic()
gg + facet_grid(Status ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

Which didn't work either, as it gave me a very messed up graph. For reference, I'd sort of like my faceted graph to end up like this one:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of data, rather copy and paste the output of `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: "I don't want to use ggplot for this as I'm specifically trying to get it to work in ggpubr." FYI - ggpubr is an extension package of ggplot2, you're still actually using ggplot2.